# Using Prototype of function constructor add new function

Tags: javascript

I want to check my idea is correct or not?

Codes:

```
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname =  lastname;
        }

        Person.prototype.getFullName = function () {
            return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
        }

        var john = new Person('Melo','Tang');
```

I call the code in the following picture "function constructor".

```
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
                this.firstname = firstname;
                this.lastname =  lastname;
            }
```

When the program run to this line

```
var john = new Person('Melo','Tang');
```

JS will use prototype chain to add the getFullName function in the "function constructor" Object and new a empty Object like following picture am I right?
[image]

Comment: The "Prototype Chain" label should be on the red arrow.

Comment: I forgot it thanks but except this there are any errors?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what your diagram or the arrows or their colors are supposed to represent.

> When the program runs to this line
>
> `var john = new Person('Melo','Tang');`

What happens here is exactly that a new object is constructed via the `Person` constructor, with `Person.prototype` as its prototype. Other than being used as the prototype for the new object, `Person.prototype` is not examined or consulted, nor is anything done with the methods on it at this time. The prototype is consulted only when **looking up** properties and methods, such as when calling `john.getFullName()`.

For clarity, I would avoid the term "function constructor object". Just call it a "constructor (function)".

Comment: torazaburo thank you. As far as I know, Prototype is a property of an object and Proto is an Object. I call "function constructor object" because I want to emphasize function constructor is an Object in JS.  I want to ask a question, the "Person.prototype"  is a property of function constructor?  If yes, getFullName function was added at Person.prototype or proto Obj?